# How to get values from yml based on input?

Tags: spring-boot, yaml, app.yaml

I am using spring-boot-starter-web latest version 2.2.6.RELEASE. I need to get value from yml file based on my input instead of @value.

If the count is 100, need to get the following values

```
key1: value1 100
key2: value2 100
```

If the count is 1000, need to get the following values

```
key1: value1 1000
key2: value2 1000
```

How can I achieve this?

My application.yml file,

```
config:
  host: http://myhost
  count-100:
      key1: value1 100
      key2: value2 100 
  count-1000:
      key1: value1 1000
      key2: value2 1000
  count-10000:
      key1: value1 10000
      key2: value2 10000
```

Java code,

```
int count = myObject.getCount();

if (count >= 100) {
  // this needs to fill from application.yml
  key1 = ""; 
  key2 = 0;
} else if (count >=1000 && count <= 10000) {
  key1 = "";
  key2 = 0;
} else {
  key1 = "";
  key2 = 0;
}
```

Any inputs here highly appreciated.

Comment: from where will be you deriving count is 100 or 1000 ? can you show the code ?

Comment: I have updated my code.

Comment: Could you please review my answer ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am checking on this, but my springboot application doesn't pick the values from application.yml.. Once I get this working.. I will do upvote your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `@ConfigurationProperties` to load the count values.

I would recommend changing your application yml to use counts as key followed by different counts.

Something like

```
config:
  host: http://myhost
  counts:
    100:
      key1: value1 100
      key2: value2 100
    1000:
      key1: value1 1000
      key2: value2 1000
    10000:
      key1: value1 10000
      key2: value2 10000
```

Create a `Counts` class

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("config")
public class Counts {
    private final Map<Integer, Map<String, String>> counts;

    public Counts(Map<Integer, Map<String, String>> counts) {
        this.counts = counts;
    }

    public Map<Integer, Map<String, String>> getCounts() {
        return counts;
    }
}
```

Java Code

```
//Autowire Counts class

int count = myObject.getCount();

Map<Integer, Map<String, String>> countMap = counts.getCounts().get(count);
  key1 = countMap.get("key1");
  key2 = countMap.get("key2");
  if (count >= 100) {

  } ....
```

If you like to keep your application yml you can use

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("config")
public class Counts {

    private final Map<String, String> count100;

    private final Map<String, String> count1000;

    private final Map<String, String> count10000;

    public Counts(Map<String, String> count100, Map<String, String> count1000, Map<String, String> count10000) {
        this.count100 = count100;
        this.count1000 = count1000;
        this.count10000 = count10000;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getCount1000() {
        return count1000;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getCount100() {
        return count100;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getCount10000() {
        return count10000;
    }
}
```

Java Code

```
    //Autowire Counts class

    int count = myObject.getCount();

    if (count >= 100) {
      Map<String, String> count100Map = counts.getCount100();
      key1 = count100Map.get("key1");
      key2 = count100Map.get("key2");;
    } ....
```